# Integration between php and flume directly or between php and java?

Tags: java, php, hbase, thrift, flume

I'm developing a client to log data in hbase using java, 
i use flume integration with hbase,
i already developed the client and my applications use it perfectly,
the problem is all the applications using the client is also developed under java,
and one of my applications developed under php,
the question is :: is there away to communicate between php and java or directly between php and flume directly to log data in hbase??

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP-Java Bridge for using Java and PHP at the same time! :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4906462/217079) you can write logs to [syslog](http://php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php) in your PHP application, and Flume can read them using one of its [syslog sources](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#syslog-sources).